# Trying to make a canvas move with keyboard -javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I know there are a lot of questions already asked about this, but it doesn't answer why my code doesn't work. I just can't wrap my head around it. Here is my code, nothing happens when I press <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd> keys.

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 40;
var y = 40;
var WIDTH = 40;
var HEIGHT = 40;
var keycode = event.keyCode;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
document.addEventListener("keydown", draw);
function draw(){
    switch(keycode){
    case 68:
        x += 5;
      break;
    case 65:
        x -= 5;
      break;
  }
  ctx.clear();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}

<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

Comment: You can see `event is not defined` error in your console. You are not inside a scope of an event handler to use the `event` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're grabbing `event.keyCode` to a variable too early and from the wrong place.

Instead, accept an argument in your `draw` function, and use the `which` property (if there and truthy) or `keyCode` property on that directly:

```
function draw(e){
// Arg -------^
    switch(e.which || e.keyCode){
// Key ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        case 68:
            x += 5;
            break;
        case 65:
            x -= 5;
            break;
  }
  ctx.clear();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}
```

Some browsers use `which`, others use `keyCode`, which is why we look for `which` and, if it's falsy, for `keyCode`.

Comment: Humm.... `a` have the 65 keycode, `d` have the 68 keycode. What's the problem exactly, @TJCrowder?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: I thought your comment "The correct ones" was about keycodes. I take it it wasn't. :-)